# Android : Is there any way to get IMEI of device using browser or browser app

Tags: android, imei

I want to get IMEI no. for Android mobiles using browser or browser app. Can anyone suggest me for this ... plz.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the IMEI Number of your Android Mobile
Requires Permission: `READ_PHONE_STATE`

```
TelephonyManager teleManager = 
    (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);  
String IMEI = teleManager.getDeviceId();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get this kind of sensitive information through the browser, but please look at this question about an application. [How to get the device's IMEI/ESN programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-programmatically-get-the-devices-imei-esn-in-android)