# Can a website block a specific iPhone device through IP, device ID or phone serial number?

Tags: iphone, security, network-programming, filtering, blocking

Just wanted to know whether websites have the capabilities to block a specific iPhone or any mobile device through Imei number or phone serial number ?

Block in the sense - not be able to use their website or features etc.

Answer (score 0):

It can't. Try to check this question for some references.

[How to Get IMEI numbers from tabs programatically in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426006/how-to-get-imei-numbers-from-tabs-programatically-in-php)

But it can block some device through the IP Address.

Comment: So there is no way that a website can block a mobile device from its IMEI ?

Comment: maybe they can block the mobile number that is being used on mobile data ? is that possible for them to see which mobile number you are using when you are using mobile data and using the website ?

Comment: No
It's also not recommended to block via ip address, as every time they access a wifi they will have different ip address, and when using cell data they are most likely using the same IP as other mobile devices connected to the same provider.