# How can I get phone serial number (IMEI)

Tags: android

I want to get phone serial number by programming to registration configuration of my application and number of users and phones that my app has been installed on them.

Can I get that?

and can I get phone model that my app has been installed on them?

Comment: To get IMEI number use this code
`TelephonyManager mngr = getSystemService(Context.Telephony_service);
mngr.getDeviceId()`

Comment: which permissions needs?

Comment: Everyone .. are there some changes in android 6? can we still access the IMEI by some means?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

pls refer this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1972404/951045

```
 TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
  mngr.getDeviceId();
```

add `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Context.Telephony_service ---> Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE

Comment: u can use:
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)myActivity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String uid = tManager.getDeviceId();

Comment: In case of Android M and above the permissions may not be granted by the user, so we need to check the same before accessing them. Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38782876/3811068

Comment: This is deprecated in API 26, please use [`getImei()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getimei)

Answer (score 9):

```
public String getIMEI(Context context){

    TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
    String imei = mngr.getDeviceId();
    return imei;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code:-

```
telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);


    deviceId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId(); 
    Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceId() " + deviceId);



    phoneType = telephonyManager.getPhoneType();
    Log.d(TAG, "getPhoneType () " + phoneType);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 final TelephonyManager tm =(TelephonyManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

  String deviceid = tm.getDeviceId();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use below code for IMEI:**

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String imei= tm.getDeviceId();
```