# Neither user 10102 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to call **[getCallCapablePhoneAccounts()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager.html#getCallCapablePhoneAccounts())** method of ***android.telecom.TelecomManager*** class. Though i have added required user-permission, i am getting **Security exception**.

Here is the line of code where i am getting exception

```
List<PhoneAccountHandle> list = getTelecomManager().getCallCapablePhoneAccounts();
```

user permission added in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

> Exception stacktrace
>        Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: getDefaultOutgoingPhoneAccount: Neither user 10102 nor current process
>   has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
>               at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
>               at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
>               at com.android.internal.telecom.ITelecomService$Stub$Proxy.getDefaultOutgoingPhoneAccount(ITelecomService.java:615)
>               at android.telecom.TelecomManager.getDefaultOutgoingPhoneAccount(TelecomManager.java:439)

Comment: What did you add to your manifest?

Comment: Try a clean and rebuild. If not, deleting the permission and re-adding it supposedly fixes things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778168/access-network-state-permisson-on-android-ics/12778460#12778460

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> this is been added in manifest

Comment: Tried clean, rebuild, but issue still exists

Comment: I am also getting the same issue, after I upgraded my emulator target android 6.
@Prasad were you able to find a solution?

Comment: It seems this is some issue with Android M

https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2938

Comment: @Rusheel, not yet found the solution. These APIs are added in level 23(android M). It seems to be a bug in the framework

Comment: @Prasad You can try to compile your app for api 23 i.e. compile sdk version 23 and target sdk version 23. While on the emulator you can run an older Android like Lollipop (API 21). This should work. I know this is just a workaround to check if your code works fine till a solution for permissions issue is released by android developers

Comment: Finally this is fixed by changing targetSdk level to 4

Answer (score 87):

On Android >=6.0, We have to request permission runtime.

Step1: add in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Step2: Request permission.

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);

if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
} else {
    //TODO
}
```

Step3: Handle callback when you request permission.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE:
            if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                //TODO
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Read official guide here [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Thank for this. Don't forget, you also need to ensure your activity `implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback`.

Comment: the right package is android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

Comment: I got this error on Xiaomi Mi 4i **os version:5.0.2** so what can i do?

Comment: REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE here is an app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the result of the request (comment from documentation).

Comment: I get **Cannot resolve symbol REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE**

Comment: Got it, I forgot this `private final int REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE=1;`

Comment: BTW, by my experience this specific permission READ_PHONE_STATE is acting somewhat strange. Tried on LG G5 API 26. It needs runtime request to be granted, but on the other hand when requested granted automatically without displaying UI, and also does not appear for the user in the app's runtime permissions.

Answer (score 54):

Are you running Android M? If so, this is because it's not enough to declare permissions in the manifest. For some permissions, you have to explicitly ask user in the runtime: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Wrong answer! I am running Android M, but targeting Android L. In such case it IS enough to declare permissions in the manifest. Correct answer to the question is to declare permission `android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` instead of `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`.

Comment: @zyamys that is not enough: if you target Android L the permission is automatically granted at installation time, but the user can always disable it from system settings.

Answer (score 10):

I was experiencing this problem on Samsung devices (fine on others).  like *zyamys* suggested in his/her comment, I added the manifest.permission line but in addition to rather than instead of the original line, so:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

I'm targeting API 22, so don't need to explicitly ask for permissions.

Answer (score 0):

after I started coding I saw the same issue about my google maps permission. After I read here I understand that same time I asked for permission. I used one bloc to emit location data and should be initialized when open. but the same time I was asking to perm. That means to me while I didn't get the permission I was trying to do something with permission. so I refactor the code first take perm grant from phone and then init all the things with the perm. maybe all kind of "..... neither user have perm.." errors come from this kind of problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).