# Using TelephonyManager to get location throws java.lang.SecurityException

Tags: android, telephonymanager

Hi in my app I am using TelephonyManager to get location. Here is the piece of code:

```
        TelephonyManager tm  = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        doPermissionCheck();
        location = (GsmCellLocation) tm.getCellLocation();//throws exception in this line
        cellID = location.getCid();
        lac = location.getLac();
```

doPermissionCheck():

```
private void doPermissionCheck() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,
                    new String[]{ Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,
                    new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION },
                    MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }
```

In my manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

This is the error:

```
04-12 13:59:39.725 6841-6841/com.example.oik.offlinemap E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.oik.offlinemap, PID: 6841
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.oik.offlinemap/com.example.oik.offlinemap.MapsActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: getCellLocation: Neither user 10057 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
        Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: getCellLocation: Neither user 10057 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.
                at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
        at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getCellLocation(ITelephony.java:2292)
        at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getCellLocation(TelephonyManager.java:826)
        at com.example.oik.offlinemap.MapsActivity.getLocation(MapsActivity.java:79)
        at com.example.oik.offlinemap.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

As you can see that I have included all the required permissions in manifest and permission check in code as well for android M, I don't know why I still get the  `**java.lang.SecurityException**`. Someone please help me.

Comment: call doPermissionCheck method before object creation tm :

Comment: I think you are running on Android M

Comment: @Amit Yes I am running android M

Comment: @Jhaman Das I already tried that, that does not work, it crashes

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: you can follow this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742327/neither-user-10102-nor-current-process-has-android-permission-read-phone-state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must wait your permission checking process finished before calling `tm.getCellLocation()`. Such as:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
    //do your request permission   
}else{
    // do your getLocation here
}
```

in your `Activity` - `onRequestPermissionsResult`, you can check is permission is granted or not then do `getLocation`.