# How to terminate an incoming call within ITelephony

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager

i am trying to disconnect incoming call but facing this error

```
 public interface ITelephony {
    boolean endCall();
    void answerRingingCall();
    void silenceRinger();
 }
 private void disconnectPhoneItelephony(Context context)
 {
    ITelephony telephonyService;
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try
    {
    telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
         telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
        telephonyService.endCall();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("error", e.toString());
    }
}
```

error:

```
(java.lang.ClassCastException:com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$
Proxy cannot be cast to belllab.com.meetingmanager.ITelephony )
```

Comment: Check that imported file package name and yours.

Comment: packge name is correct

Comment: see if you have added ITelephony.AIDL file in your project? and if you have added then your package name mustbe package name must be com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.AIDL

Comment: no i have not added that file

Comment: where that file is added and how can i get this file

Comment: Rameshbabu plz guide me

Comment: is this solved your problem. Then please select it as a answer.

Comment: it not solve my problem

Comment: did you get the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have added ITelephony.AIDL file in your project? If not download from [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/ncid/ncidandroid/ci/344800b8405919d1dbee54848ad37dc0efdf6a18/tree/src/com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.aidl) and add it to your project.

You have to add the file like this

[image]

Also then your package name must be com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.AIDL:

Check this [tutorial](http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2010/10/blocking-incoming-call-android.html) to implement Aidl file

Comment: not working now it is giving erro on it telephony in code

Comment: Update the code you implemented along with log cat report. So that i can able to check.

Comment: it is giving error on it telephony that unable to resolve the variable

Comment: i just import the aidal file

Comment: @Hami check my updated answer that i have included tutorial to implement it. Go through it

Comment: i have done it but how to import this aidl file in code

Comment: create a new package in the name of com.android.internal.telephony and paste the file inside this package and compile it.

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10191 nor current process has android.permission.CALL_PHONE.

Comment: On Android >=6.0, We have to request runtime permission.

Comment: i have given these permission. by going in the setting and allow the requested permission but still the error

Comment: 06-20 16:48:24.095 16250-16250/belllab.com.meetingmanager D/error: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10191 nor current process has android.permission.CALL_PHONE.

Comment: check this answer and have implemented same like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38782876/2556660