# I added download function on my webview app but when i press download button app crashes

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webView;
String url = "https://svidzdownloader.com/";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
     public void onDownloadStart(String s, String s1, String s2, String s3, 
     long l) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"Download");
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
        }
    });



}
```

I have made a webview app and i want to download videos from my webview app and i have add the download function code above but this code is not working when i press download button my app crashes

Comment: What error do you see in the logcat? Please add the logcat to your question too.

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to write to /storage/emulated/0/Download/Download: Neither user 10143 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: this my logcat and i have written permission on my manifest write external srorage

Comment: even i have add perimission in menifest this code dosent work and i have seen this code on stack over flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **No permission to write** to `/storage/emulated/0/Download/Download`:
>   Neither user 10143 nor current process has
>   `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Go to `AndroidManifest.xml` and above of `<application` tag add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

---

It seems like you'll need runtime permission too. Add the following codes inside your `onDownloadStart` for example:

```
@Override
public void onDownloadStart(String s, String s1, String s2, String s3, 
             long l) {

                   if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission has not been granted.
                 // Request for the permission like adding a function which will do that

                  requestPermission(); // a function to request permissions

            } else {

               // Permission granted!! do your stuff here

                 DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                 request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();

                 request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                 request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"Download");
                 DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                 dm.enqueue(request);


          }
 });
```

Function to request permission:

```
private void requestPermission() {
        Log.i(TAG, "permission has NOT been granted. Requesting permission.");
            private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL = 0;


        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
            // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
            // For example if the user has previously denied the permission.
            Log.i(TAG,
                    "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");
            Snackbar.make(mLayout, R.string.permission_camera_rationale,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL);
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        } else {

            // permission has not been granted yet. Request it directly.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL);
        }

    }
```

Check this link: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

And this: [Neither user 10102 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742327/neither-user-10102-nor-current-process-has-android-permission-read-phone-state)

Comment: i have add permission as well why this is not working

Comment: You'll need runtime permission too. I've updated my answer. please have a look

Comment: these two answer where i will have add these answer in my code i asking this

Comment: Add them inside your `Activity`. If you read [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting), everything will be clear to understand.

Comment: please the answer you  have wrote add this answer into my code above

Comment: There is a good sample from google [in here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/system/runtimepermissions/MainActivity.java) which you can use. Use the first line of codes inside your `onDownloadStart` then first check if user accepted the permission, then do your stuff. Use the link I've provided.

Comment: just please add answer is my default code so i can understant in the link i cannot understand

Comment: Please check the updated answer. However, this is not how Stack Overflow works. We don't code for users. We help them instead ;) I've added explanation in the codes as comments.

Comment: ok after we add this code we have to initilaize the mehtod on oncreate??

Comment: No. You'll just need  `implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback` in your Activity. Check this example: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/system/runtimepermissions/MainActivity.java

Comment: snackbar is getting red on android studio??

Comment: Please ask this (with added codes inside) in another question. So that we can help you better.