# Android's WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission issue on Samsung Galaxy Api 23 version 6

Tags: android, pdf, android-permissions

I need to open a pdf using a uri.
I have the code in place to open the pdf. 
My code works fine on Api greater than 23.
I get the following SecurityException when I try to download the file on a Samsung Galaxy device with Api 23 and version 6.

Here is the exception:

```
01-25 19:28:38.723 6655-6667/android.process.media E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to write to /storage/emulated/0/Download/Canto Quick Start Guide.pdf: Neither user 10022 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
        at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1438)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1470)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextWrapper.java:675)
        at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider.checkFileUriDestination(DownloadProvider.java:724)
        at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider.insert(DownloadProvider.java:558)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:263)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:163)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:507)
```

I have setup the required permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I have the following check in place to test if the user does not have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission then ask the user for granting access.

```
int PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 2;
    //             Check whether this app has write external storage permission or not.
                int writeExternalStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                // If do not grant write external storage permission.
                if (writeExternalStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Request user to grant write external storage permission.
                    ((MainActivity)activity).getSharedPreferenceManager().add(PreferenceConstants.SHAREPOINT_FILE_URI, getUrl((SharepointFile) object, activity));
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PermissionConstants.PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getUrl((SharepointFile) object, activity)));
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(getUrl((SharepointFile) object, activity)), "application/pdf");
                    activity.startActivity(intent);

                }
```

I override the onRequestPermissionResult in MainActivity.java so that as soon as the user grants permission then the download can be initiated.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case PermissionConstants.PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                String fileUri = getSharedPreferenceManager().get(PreferenceConstants.SHAREPOINT_FILE_URI);

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(fileUri));

                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                getSharedPreferenceManager().remove(PreferenceConstants.SHAREPOINT_FILE_URI);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

I have the code to ask the user for permission. I do get the dialog/alert to allow access. Once the user clicks allow, I see that it still gives the above exception. I went in settings to check my app's permission and see that it is turned "on" for storage. Why would I still get permission issue? Any pointers on what I could be missing here? Appreciate your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neither user 10102 nor current process has android.permission.READ\_PHONE\_STATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742327/neither-user-10102-nor-current-process-has-android-permission-read-phone-state)

Answer (score 0):

It is just an assumption but i see you have declared both

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) says:

> Any app that declares the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is implicitly granted this (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission.

Try to remove

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```