# Android NFC: Can we uniquely identify the NFC beam of each mobile device?

Tags: android, nfc

I just had a simple clarification. Is it possible to uniquely identify each mobile device using the NFC beam it projects? May be from some NFC tags. Basically I wanted to know suppose I switch on NFC of two mobile devices, Can one mobile device identify the other mobile device if it had previously communicated with it? Is there any unique ID related to NFC associated with every mobile device?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your question related to programming ?
I don't think NFC on mobile devices has an UID. A device can already be identified with the IMEI number (International Mobile Equipment Identity) so you're up to identify the other device by getting his IMEI number from NFC (e.g from an app).
However, as you noticed, NFC tags contain an UID corresponding to several parameters (manufacturer, product...)

Comment: Yes.. this is a program related qustion since  i'm planning of writing an app that uniquely identifies other mobiles using NFC..

Comment: The UID is unique by definition so you'll get the same for every device.
Use this link to see how to get the IMEI of a phone : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-programmatically-get-the-devices-imei-esn-in-android