# How do you release the .apk for an Android app for specific people?

Tags: java, android, apk

Okay, so I'm working on a project where I need to create an android app (for which I'm using the Eclipse IDE). My supervisor has asked me for the `apk` file, but how do I do this? Note that the program is not yet completed, but it does not have errors (i.e, it will work if he runs it, but its not something I want the general public to be using). I would preferably like a method that would later allow me to update the app as I work on code and finally release my final version (which would allow the general public to upload as well).

Please advise!

Comment: Maybe you should you testflight for beta testing and private distrubution? https://testflightapp.com/dashboard/

Comment: @MP23: TestFlight discontinued Android support.

Comment: Have you done any searching yet? If you had, you probably would have found things like Google Play's beta-testing settings, or test-flight. You can always send the apk via email, and updates, too.

Comment: In your workspace look for the bin folder, in that you will find the APK.

Comment: Send the supervisor the APK file via email. Or copy it to a file server. Or put it on a USB thumb drive. Or any other conventional means of getting a file to another person.

Comment: Do **not** take it out of the bin folder, as some of the less experienced members seem to recommend. This will be an apk signed with a debug-key, which will expire quickly. Create a production key and sign it with that, through export... then use the various methods above to distribute it.

Answer (score 0):

The android developer console provides beta and alpha staging. You can create google groups or google+ communities to let your beta/alpha testers join.

Here you can read more about [staged rollouts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)

Answer (score -1):

An easy method:
 1. Add a new activity. 
 2. Set a password to it.
 3. Set the new activity as 
        the new launcher.

A more Advanced method:

1. Read your boss's deviceID like IMEI code. [Learn how to do it
   here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-programmatically-get-the-devices-imei-esn-in-android)
2. Check in your launcher Activity to finish if the deviceID is not equal to your boss's deviceID.

Finally, in the higher app versions simply remove the authentication Activities.

Comment: I'm in awe as to how little this "answer" has to do with the question.

Comment: It is an alternative, pushing the questioner towards being more reasonable.

Comment: I've provided three actual options in my comment. Besides, a comment does not need to be an answer, but rather help the answer along. Please refer to the stackoverflow faq. Telling the asker to make his apk available to the public, but password-protecting it, isn't "more reasonable."

Comment: Well you are right because I supposed he is aware of Signing process and I  thought maybe I could ultimately guide him towards the use of IMEI which in my experience is great for enterprise and commercial products.