# prevent un authorization for iOS and android app

Tags: android, ios, mobile, ios7

I am developing iOS and android application. I want to prevent the user from logging in into the app from the different devices which may have different sim card into the devices.

For Example, If user has device A and he logged in into the app, then he cannot get log in into the app from other devices called as device B which has different sim card. Also, please note that if the user has a same mobile number on different devices, then he is an authorize user and can log in into the app.

So, Can i put restriction based on user's sim card details? or else what can i do to prevent the users from getting an unauthorized log in into the app?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IMEI number of devices. By using IMEI number you can restrict them. Hope it helps. Thank you!!

Comment: is there any chances to get app rejected from app store or play store if i am using IMEI number?

Comment: In android it won't. I am not sure about app store. You can use this link for getting IMEI in android "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-programmatically-get-the-devices-imei-esn-in-android" . Hope it helps you. Thank you buddy

Comment: You cannot access the IMEI or any other unique tracking ID for the device on iOS