# Add IMEI number in android application?

Tags: java, android, imei

I have to add an IMEI number in this mail body part.  I tried on this method, but i can't.

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager =(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

How can I get and print in body part IMEI number ?

```
public void sendMail(String body, String sender, String recipients, String scilNo)
        throws Exception {
    try {


        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/TEB/Log");
        folder.mkdirs();
        String extStorageDirectory = folder.toString();

        SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy__HH-mm-ss");
        now = new Date();
        String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);
        File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, strDate + ".txt");

        file.createNewFile();

        String cmd = "logcat -d -v long -f " + file.getAbsolutePath()
                + " *:V";
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);

        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(file.getName());

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(String.format("%10s: %s\n", "Gönderen", scilNo));
        sb.append(String.format("%10s: %s\n", "Mesaj", body ));

        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(sb.toString().getBytes(), "text/plain"));

        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(handler);

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);

        final MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setContent(multipart);
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
        message.setSubject("Hata Bildirim Mesajı");


        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0) {
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
        } else {
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(recipients));
        }

        Thread mySend = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
                    transport.connect(mailhost, user, password);
                    transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
                    Transport.send(message, message.getAllRecipients());
                    transport.close();
                    LogUtil.i("Mail SEND DONE");
                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    LogUtil.e("GMailSender.sendMail.MessagingException", e);
                }
            }

        });
        mySend.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogUtil.e("GMailSender.sendMail.Exception", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically get the devices IMEI/ESN in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-programmatically-get-the-devices-imei-esn-in-android)

Comment: Have you included <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

Comment: What is the error you are getting when you try to use telephonyManager.getDeviceId()? Post the logcat.

Comment: How did you solve? what was the error/mistake?

Comment: due to an error from me. I tried to use the codes wrong class. It was my fault. Other than that, no error in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to add this in the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Then try this -

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

In emulator, you'll probably get a like a "00000..." value. getDeviceId() returns NULL if device ID is not available.

View [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-programmatically-get-the-devices-imei-esn-in-android) link for reference.

Comment: Great. Please mark any of the answers provided to this question as "Accepted".

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
   Log.d("Emi::", ">" + telephonyManager.getDeviceId());
```

with the following permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: I used that code. But I wrote to the wrong place. An error caused from me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

telephonyManager.getDeviceId();