# Find IMEI number of connected device

Tags: .net, mobile, tablet, imei

I am developing a windows desktop application for copying proprietary data to devices, mobile and pad only. For doing that we are asked to use IMEI number of the device to uniquely identify it. When the customer connects the device, my application in C# is able to detect a device is connected over USB. But I am not finding a way to read the IMEI number of the device.

Please suggest me a way to read the IMEI number of the device. I am open to all programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

for windows mobile device:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161389/Windows-Mobile-Programming-Tricks-on-the-NET-Com

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/78856/get-imei-in-device-application-in-C-Sharp-dotnet.aspx

for android device:
[How to get the device's IMEI/ESN programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-programmatically-get-the-devices-imei-esn-in-android)

Comment: The links you provided are useful when you are running an application on the device itself. I am looking at a solution where my application is running on a PC and I want to find the IMEI number of the device connected through USB.