# How to get device imei number in non-activity class?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am trying to make a non-activity class for some useful functions like getting device Imei number.
But when i am using

```
    mngr = (TelephonyManager)myContext(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

it is giving me this error:

```
    The method myContext(String) is undefined for the type FunctionsForWorking
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically get the devices IMEI/ESN in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-programmatically-get-the-devices-imei-esn-in-android)

Comment: Sorry getSystemServices is also not working in non-activity class

Comment: FunctionsForWorking is a class Extending Service

Comment: Why not pass activity context in the constructor of the non-activity class and use it?

Comment: Service is calling one of its methods.How Can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service has its own context you can use that, for your concern about getting the IMEI in a service use below code:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.v("ranjith","started service");
        TelephonyManager c=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String device_id = c.getDeviceId();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

For your question about how to pass context to non-Activity class, the answer is just pass it as a parameter in the constructor to the other class, for eg:-

```
public class myActivityclass extends Activity{
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
        nonActivityclass c=new nonActivityclass(Context context);
        -----------------------------
}
```

In the non-Activity class:

```
public class nonActivityclass{
Context context;
public nonActivityclass(Context context)
{
         this.context=context
}
//you can use context now
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ranjith.It was a great idea.Worked! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm calling a thread in my App.java class -> OnCreate method, and I'm getting the device IMEI like this:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

`String IMEI = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();`

It's enough passing the context through parameters to your implementation