# How to find default IMEI number

Tags: android, smartphone

I want to know if there is a way to find out the default IMEI number of an android phone...
I mean that I want to know if the IMEI number has been changed by the person who owns the phone.

Comment: You can find the answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-programmatically-get-the-devices-imei-esn-in-android, this seems like duplicate.

Comment: I dont want  to find the IMEI number programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You want to call [TelephonyManager.getDeviceId().](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29)

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

And you should add the following permission into your Manifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

> Be careful about doing this. Not only will users wonder why your
>   application is accessing their telephony stack, it might be difficult
>   to migrate data over if the user gets a new device.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I am not developing an app to do this... I want to know if there is a way to find the number without developing an app.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not trying to find IMEI from code but directly viewing phone that's simple. Just dial *#06# from your phone or alternatively checking in your phone following:

Settings - About Phone - Status - SIM card Status -IMEI

No IMEI doesn't change.