# How To Uniquely Identify An Android Device? even after change the system or factory reset.

Tags: android

I wonder maybe there are some ways to get some hardware info, and then make an unique id for this phone based on these info.

Is that possible?

Comment: Please go through  http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

Comment: I see these posts, but these ids change when reset and install an different ROM on your phone.

Comment: You could try to get the IMEI, but it can be changed too!

Comment: so are there any unchangeable infos?

Answer (score 0):

You can use device IMEI number. Most of case it's unique.

check this post -> [How to get the device's IMEI/ESN programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-get-the-devices-imei-esn-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: IMEI is also changeable

Answer (score -1):

As you read there isn't a 100% safe method to get a unique id. Another approach that you can use (if you want a unique identifier for your app) is to generate a random UUID at your first install and save it locally;

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
preferences.setAppId(uuid.toString());
```

Comment: Luis wants something that will persist after a factory reset of the phone - this will not.