# Can I allow installing app only on certain verified devices?

Tags: android, installation, android-install-apk

I want to restrict my application to install only allowed device. That is while installing the app I want to fetch the device information like imei number. Then I want to check the imei number if it is valid or not using my restored database of imei.

Is that possible?

Comment: Very well explained, how to and disadvantages: [Already answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-get-the-devices-imei-esn-programmatically-in-android)