# Get username ,password, location and imei number of current device and send it to server?

Tags: android, retrofit2, androidhttpclient

Hey guys i design an app in which i have to get username and password for authetication then current location and IMEI number of the current device.Then send it to server I am new to this concept.I want anybody to guide me.(android login screen with php)

Comment: show us what all have you done.

Comment: Anyways IMEI can be extracted using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-get-the-devices-imei-esn-programmatically-in-android

Comment: i am done in  my designing part.I don't know how to start

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: i need any example program for http request to send parameters

Comment: This is not the website where developers code for you.They just can help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fatch all the contains and store in to the string after that you need to use any http request maker such as "Asynchronous Http Client", "volly", "Retrofit"and post to server using API.

Comment: thanks buddy.....i am new to these concepts..but i am learning now...if u know  the best site to study....link the url

Comment: androidhive.info