# How to get the country for which android device is manufactured for?

Tags: android

From my little experience in telecom industry, I learnt that when a mobile is working in some country, it has to follow the regulations imposed by the country government. So to follow the regulations, OEMs may either manufacture the device for specific country or set of countries following their regulations. If the device is manufactured for specific country, is there any standard way to get it?

Reading the ro.product.locale or persist.sys.locale is of no help as they give us the locale values. They mayn't provide information about the country for which device is manufactured for.

Example: I am using one android phone bought in India. When I read ro.product.locale or persist.sys.locale, it is giving en-US. But I need to get India.

Is there any standard way of querying for the country for which device is manufactured.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the IMEI number and use the 7th and 8th numbers to determine the country.

This is a link showing how you can extract IMEI number

[How to get the device's IMEI/ESN programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-get-the-devices-imei-esn-programmatically-in-android/#3009341)

Source: http://www.samsungsfour.com/tutorials/find-out-galaxy-smartphone-country-of-origin-from-imei-code.html

Comment: Thanks for providing me such a nice information. I dig little more and found from the Wikipedia that this is applicable to models manufactured till 2002. From 2003, FAC(Final assembly code) ceased to exist. And also, if I understand correct, this code only gives location of manufacturing factory. But I need to get for which country the device is manufactured.

Comment: I'm glad I could help