# How to distinguish between android devices?

Tags: java, android, firebase

When I first log in, I want to get and write some native android device code to the Realtime Database Firebase, so that with a single login and password, I can only log in from one device (from which the first login was made). What code and how to get it to distinguish between android devices? I do all this with Java and Real time Database Firebase.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-get-the-devices-imei-esn-programmatically-in-android

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

Answer (score 0):

You can get an identifier like IMEI and update it in the database this way:

```
const deviceImei = android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()

public void updateUserDevice(String userId, String identifier) {
    User user = new User(name, identifier);
    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
}
```

Though using IMEI is not recommended for identification purposes about which you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1972404/).
Other option would be getting device android ID, which does not require any special permission:

```
String device_unique_id = Secure.getString(activity.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```